# How to install minimum footprint of FZF with bash on OpenWrt?

Tags: openwrt, fzf

Is there a way to have FZF running with bash on OpenWrt and not consume a lot of ROM space?

Answer (score 0):

**The following instructions will install FZF on OpenWrt router with a footprint of around 3.3 MB.**

1. Temporary install FZF from GitHub:

```
ssh OpenWrt-Router

cd /tmp
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git fzf
./fzf/install

mkdir ~/fzf
cp ./fzf/bin/fzf ~/fzf/
cp ./fzf/shell/completion.bash ~/fzf/
cp ./fzf/shell/key-bindings.bash ~/fzf/
rm ~/.fzf.bash
rm -fr ./fzf
```

2. Add the following to ~/.bashrc

```
# Setup FZF
FZF=~/.fzf
[ -f $FZF/fzf.bash ] && source $FZF/fzf.bash
```

3. Create file ~/fzf/fzf.bash with the following:

```
[ -n "$FZF" ] && {
    PATH="${PATH:+${PATH}:}$FZF"
    source $FZF/completion.bash
    source $FZF/key-bindings.bash
}
```